# Qual a diferença de "include" e "extend" no Ruby?

Tags: ruby, include

Estou estudando Ruby, e acabei percebendo que existem 2 formas (talvez existam mais) de injetar métodos dentro de uma classe. De início eu pensei que eles poderiam ser as mesmas coisas, já que o Ruby é uma linguagem que tem como objetivo ser bastante flexível para programadores.

Porém, eu acabei de assistir a uma aula onde o professor explicou sobre `hook` e os métodos `self.included`, `self.extended` e `self.inherited`, e isso me fez pensar: *"Será que essas duas formas abaixo realmente não possuem diferença alguma ?*
"

**Utilizando o `include`:**

```
class MinhaClasse
    include Modulo
end
```

**Utilizando o `extend`:**

```
class MinhaClasse
    extend Modulo
end
```

Existe alguma diferença entre usar o `extend` e `include` ? Se sim qual é a diferença e quando eu deveria utilizar cada uma delas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diferença é que o `include` injeta os métodos de um módulo para dentro de uma classe ou de um outro módulo como *métodos de instância*. Já o `extend`, os injeta como *métodos de classe*. Ainda com dúvidas sobre esses dois carinhas ? Vamos ver um exemplo então **:-)**

Para servir de exemplo, criaremos um módulo chamado `TestModule` que terá um método chamado `hello`:

```
module TestModule
    def hello
        puts "Hello World!"
    end
end
```

Agora vamos criar uma classe vazia e utilizar o `include` para adicionar o método.

```
class Test
    include TestModule
end

Test.new.hello  # Não gera erro
Test.hello      # Gera erro
```

Ao executar este código, podemos ver que o método é chamado e a mensagem é impressa perfeitamente, porém logo depois este erro é lançado:

> undefined method `hello' for Test:Class (NoMethodError)

Isso acontece porque definimos o método `hello` para ser um *método de instância* e na última linha nós tentamos chamar o método como se fosse um *método de classe*. Agora vamos testar o mesmo código, só que dessa vez utilizando o `extend`.

```
class Test
    extend TestModule
end

Test.hello      # Não gera erro  (eu troquei a ordem das linha para o erro ser gerado depois)
Test.new.hello  # Gera erro
```

Assim como no exemplo anterior, neste código a mensagem `"Hello World!"` é impressa e logo após um erro é gerado:

> undefined method `hello' for #‹Test:0x0000000004dfe090› (NoMethodError)

Se você reparar bem, as duas mensagens de erro são diferentes. Isso porque no primeiro exemplo, não existia um método de classe (a mensagem de erro mostra que tentamos chamar um método de `Test:Class`) chamado `hello`.

Já no segundo exemplo, não existia um método de instância (a mensagem de erro mostra que tentamos chamar um método de `<Test:0x0000000004dfe090>`) chamado `hello`.

---

Resumindo tudo:

**Include:** Injeta os métodos para ser chamado com uma instância. (Test.new.hello)

**Extend:** Injeta os métodos para ser chamado com a classe. (Test.hello)